# ReactJS - Convert JSON Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I need help for simple question, to convert this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "data_1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        "data_2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "value": "value2"
        }
    }]
}
```

To this:

I need help for simple question, to convert this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data_1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        "data_2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "value": "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Need to remove '[]'.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to make a deep copy of those inner objects, and create a new object with them. There are many ways to do this but one of the easiest methods is to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) them (ie the first element of the array), and then [parse that string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). That way new references are built, and changes to the original data won't have an effect on the new data.

```js
const data={data:[{data_1:{name:"name1",value:"value1"},data_2:{name:"name2",value:"value2"}}]};

// Stringify, and then parse the string
const copy = (o) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));

// Assemble the new object by copying the part
// for reuse
const out = { data: copy(data.data[0]) };

// Check that changes made to the original object
// are not reflected in the new object
data.data[0].data_1.name = 'bob';

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it's easy enough. You just need to return 0 element from `data` array.

Here is an example in JavaScript:

```js
const original = {
  data: [{
    data_1: {
      name: "name1",
      value: "value1"
    },
    data_2: {
      name: "name2",
      value: "value2"
    }
  }]
};

const converted = {
  data: original.data[0]
};
```

Comment: If `original` changes `converted` will also reflect those changes which maybe a sideeffect the OP doesn't want.